# Como redirecionar página após login em php?

Tags: php, html

Olá gostaria de saber como poderia  redirecionar página após login do usuario. Tem o Index que é o código abaixo e ai vem outras paginas tipo . pedidos.php , reserva.php e outras só que todas estão linkadas em pedidos.php .

então gostaria de saber como posso redirecionar após o login para pedidos.php

esse é o meu index de login

```
<div id="cadastro">
    <form method="post" action="?go=logar">
        <table id="login_table">
            <tr>
                <td>Usuário:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="txt" maxlength="15" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Senha:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name="senha" id="senha" class="txt" maxlength="15" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Entrar" class="btn" id="btnEntrar"> 
                    &nbsp;<a href="cadastro.php"><input type="button" value="Cadastre-se" class="btn" id="btnCad"></a></td>
            </tr>   
        </table>
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>

<?php
if(@$_GET['go'] == 'logar'){
    $user = $_POST['usuario'];
    $pwd = $_POST['senha'];

    if(empty($user)){
        echo "<script>alert('Preencha todos os campos para logar-se.'); history.back();</script>";
    }elseif(empty($pwd)){
        echo "<script>alert('Preencha todos os campos para logar-se.'); history.back();</script>";
    }else{
        $query1 = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM USUARIO WHERE USUARIO = '$user' AND SENHA = '$pwd'"));
        if($query1 == 1){
            echo "<script>alert('Usuário logado com sucesso.');</script>"; 
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0, url=./_painel/'>";
        }else{
            echo "<script>alert('Usuário e senha não correspondem.'); history.back();</script>";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
$query1 = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM USUARIO WHERE USUARIO = '$user' AND SENHA = '$pwd'"));
        if($query1 == 1){
            header("Location: pedidos.php");
        }else{
            echo "<script>alert('Usuário e senha não correspondem.'); history.back();</script>";
        }
```

ou

```
$query1 = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM USUARIO WHERE USUARIO = '$user' AND SENHA = '$pwd'"));
        if($query1 == 1){
            echo "<script>location.href='pedidos.php'</script>";
        }else{
            echo "<script>alert('Usuário e senha não correspondem.'); history.back();</script>";
        }
```

Espero que ajude

Answer (score 4):

É simples, você só precisa incluir essa linha no php:

```
<?php header('Location:pedidos.php');?>
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Coloquei no index  header('Location:pedidos.php'); mas tenho uma tela de cadastro e quando cadastra ela já vai pro sistema sem passar pelo index que é de login .

Comment: coloca dentro do  if($query1 == 1){, porque se colocar antes ele já vai direto

Comment: @allanaraujo, não entendi o que quis dizer com isso "mas tenho uma tela de cadastro e quando cadastra ela já vai pro sistema sem passar pelo index que é de login ". Você quer que isso aconteça? Tipo quando ele cadastra, ja vai pro sistema?

Comment: não tenho a tela de cadastro ai o usuario de cadastra e logo após tem a de login e quando o usuario faz login ele é redirecionado para o sistema

Comment: Ah sim, achei que você tinha compreendido que deveria ter adicionado essa linha após o login ser autenticado...